# Cross Referenced VLOOKUP returning column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to collect information from a column in a referenced table (SQL Server Query) in side a MS Excel spreadsheet.

There are two variables that need to be referenced (date of sale and selling agent); after validation, the result should return number of items sold.

Destination:
[Sample Spread Sheet to be populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKLU9.png)

Source:
[Source SQL Server Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNu78.png)

I have tried the below however the problem is the match returns the row number and no column is return.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP($B20,ALL_SLS_VIEW[#Data],MATCH(RIGHT(TEST_SLSR!E18,3),ALL_SLS_VIEW[sls_rep],0),FALSE),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, this should work for you.

Paste this in cell E11 of your 'To be populated' spreadsheet:

```
=SUMIFS(ALL_SLS_VIEW[SALES],ALL_SLS_VIEW[date_entered],$B11,ALL_SLS_VIEW[sls_rep],MID($E$9,FIND("- ",$E$9)+2,256))
```

It will Sum sales based on the Date in column B and the Sales Rep name at the end of cell E9.

Let me know if this does not work for your purpose.

Comment: You're amazing. ... I have been using VLOOKUP, MATCH, INDEX combinations all day and couldn't get it done. I will have to research SUMIFS a bit more to understand the logic, but it worked perfectly! Greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: @SMHorus happy to help!